# Accessing inner value in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object such as:

```
myObj = { name: { Value1: "a", Value2: "b" }}
```

how do I access **Value1** ?

**I can't use name**, i.e. `myObj.name` because it is some abstract class and name is different per input.

I do know the name but it is held in another variable that I receive from the server

so my current input is:

```
name = "someName"
```

and

```
myObj = { name: { Value1: "a", Value2: "b" }}
```

**and I need to retrieve** `"a"`

any suggestions ?

Comment: `myObj.name.Value1`

Comment: I can't use that. name is different per input.

Comment: OK, then [`myObj.name[variable]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: I can't. for example: one input will be:
```{ name1 : { value1: "a", value3: "b" }}```and another input will be: ```{ name2 : { value1: "a", value3: "b" }}```

Comment: OK... 1. That wasn't clear from the question 2. what's the problem with using the variable elsewhere `obj[whateverTheNameIs].value1`?

Comment: got it now - thanks !!